# Play Framework: How to convert a List to a JsArray

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following `List`...

```
val list = List("one", "one", "two", "two", "three", "three")
```

... how do I convert it to a `JsArray` like this?

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

As you can see, I also need to drop duplicates.

Comment: Seriously, I don't get why this question get so many down-votes :P

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a fine question to me.

Comment: I think it's because the question is *really* asking how to make the list distinct, which is a more general scala question that happens to have been asked many times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJson) is should be like this:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

Json.toJson(List("one", "one", "two", "two", "three", "three").distinct)
```